# Pegar um JSON usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, django

O Django cria um arquivo chamado *views.py*, no qual eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
def carro_view(request,carro_slug=None):
    evento = Evento.objects.filter(time = '11:28:30').distinct()
    data = []
    for x in evento:
        data.append({
        "latitude": x.lat.replace(',', '.'),
        "longitude": x.lon.replace(',', '.'),
        "title": x.carro         
        })
    marker = {"markers": data }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(marker), content_type="application/json")
```

Gostaria de saber de que maneira eu poderia pegar esse JSON em um arquivo JS, sei que existe o `getJSON(url, function(data))`, mas de que maneira eu poderia usar isso para resgatar o retorno da função na *views.py*??

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Se você possui em `urls.py` um roteamento associando uma determinada URL a essa função, basta usar essa URL em `getJSON` (provavelmente, usando um segundo argumento para escolher o carro, tipo `getJSON(url, { carro_slug:... }, function(data)`) e ao retornar o objeto JavaScript já decodificado estará disponível no parâmetro `data`. (P.S. Assumindo que você se refere ao `$.getJSON` do jQuery - não conheço outro)